# Ways of implementing Unit of Work in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orm, repository, unit-of-work

I'm currently researching how to add the [Unit of Work pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) to my existing ASP.NET MVC application that uses NHibernate.  I'm seeing a lot of variety in the various implementations and I'm having trouble determining which methods will work best in a given situation.

To help, I thought I would ask the Stack Overflow community to list their favorite ways of implementing the Unit of Work pattern in their ASP.NET MVC applications.

Maybe you use IoC to instantiate an NHibernate session when you create your controller and then pass that on to the repository.  Or maybe you create a unit of work class/interface.  Don't hesitate to link to additional resources after you describe your approach.

Also, be sure to list any pros and cons associated with your method should they exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I implemented a Repository / UoW pattern around Entity Framework 4 POCO objects and it has turned out very well for us.  We only expose the UoW to the Business/Service layer and have the Controller, or the Presenter in our case, to call these services to execute or retrieve data.

The pattern that we implemented used the following article as a guide: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff714955.aspx

Answer (score 3):

This is a fantastic guide on the subject which I have used to great success with unit tests

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application